# Correct permissions for dylib and so libs on macOS

Tags: macos, permissions, chmod

I am building an installer for my application. What would be the correct permissions for *.dylib on macOS and *.so files on Linux? Do they need the execution bit or could they be installed as 644, or even just 444 with root:wheel as owner?